# Reading word input fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net, office-interop

Ok so im trying to make a word doc that contains input fields. When the user is done and sends to document to the server i would like to read all theese fields and skip all the rest..

I'm having trouble locating how to read theese tags from my application.

[image: Inputfields]

The example template can be found here:[Here](http://sneakattack.se/media/template.docx)

What I want is to read the text for each tag and save it.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application ap = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        try
        {

            Document doc = ap.Documents.Open(txtFile.Text, ReadOnly: true, Visible: false);
            doc.Activate();


            //What to do here?


            ap.Documents.Close(SaveChanges: false, OriginalFormat: false, RouteDocument: false);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            txtRes.Text += "Exception Caught: " + ex.Message + Environment.NewLine;
        }
```

Comment: Is your app ASP.NET or Windows Service or similar ?

Comment: ok - please see my answer below...

Answer (score 1):

Office Interop is **not supported** by MS in server-like scenarios (like ASP.NET or Windows Service or similar) - see http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2 !

You will need to use some library to achieve what you want:

- [MS provides the OpenXML SDK V 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28office.14%29.aspx) (free)
- [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) (commercial)

**EDIT - as per comments:**

BEWARE that the following works ONLY in a normal application (NOT ASP.NET etc.!)...

You will basically need to go through the `Fields` collection of the `Document` (in your code that is `doc`)... some helpful links are:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.field_members.aspx
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/amrish_deep/WordAutomation05102007223934PM/WordAutomation.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range_members.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa192495%28v=office.11%29.aspx#wordobject_link8

Comment: not supported but still doable. Lets say i just want to use it on a client application then.

Comment: "doable" means that you will have to circumvent a whole lot of problems including security measures which have been tightened since Vista! please read the first link!

Comment: ok then don't think it as a server application and please (if you are able) provide an answer how to do this via client applications.. See my example code i question

Comment: useful links but can't see anywhere where it shows how to get a hold of only input fields like my template has.

Answer (score 0):

it may be helpful:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
    ...    

        Word.Application word = new Word.ApplicationClass();
        object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object path = @"D:\test.doc";
        object readOnly = false;
        Word.Document document = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);

        foreach (Word.FormField ff in document.FormFields)
        {
          MessageBox.Show(ff.Name." - ".ff.Result);
        }

        document.Close(ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
        word.Quit();
```